# Is there a way to not read .env when hitting API route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.5.42, when I setup a basic API route (api.php), and I attempt to hit that endpoint, it seems like Laravel wants to read from .ENV.

For **example**, when I hit a basic API route/endpoint Laravel attempts to read values from the .env file (like reading values for session state server, etc).  I don't want it to do that for certain API routes.

Why would it try to read from .ENV for things like session server when it doesn't need to?  The route isn't behind any authentication.

I have feeling Laravel starts up some internal workings on every request. How can I have it NOT do that for simple routes like this one.

For example, here's my route:

```
Route::get('/something', function() {
    response('', 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
});
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-disable-session-and-cookies-for-some-routes

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using? Did you upgrade to it from an earlier version or install it at that version?

Comment: I don't think reading from `.env` (via `config/` files generally) is the same as starting/reading from session. You are correct that there is overhead on every request when using Laravel, but preventing that might cause more problems than is worth.

Comment: @RossWilson I am using 5.5.42. I've updated the question to include that. I did a straight install - no upgrade.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. You might be right - session startup might be different than reading from .ENV.  My assumption was that reading from .ENV was a direct result of starting the session.  I've updated my question to specify not wanting to read from .ENV.

Comment: Sorry; not sure what happened with the edit there; went to add a tag and something went haywire

Comment: Anywho, check the `index.php` file in `public/`; that's the entry point for I believe all requests and shows what happens; `bootstrap/autoload.php` is called, as well as `bootstrap/app.php`, which loads a whole bunch of things, including settings from `.env`. If you were to disable that, I doubt the request would even process correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration data is used for a lot more than just sessions.  Typically, .env is read to load data into various config files.

Cache the configuration then the configuration files and .env file will no longer be read on requests.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

The request life cycle goes something like this:

- Hit public/index.php
- Create the application

  - Register Event/Log/Routing service providers
- Create single instances of the Console and HTTP Kernels
- Pass the request to the Kernel to handle
- Determine if the application has been bootstrapped

  - If it has not, load the bootstrappers

This is where we stop. At this point, if the application has not been bootstrapped the following will be executed:

```
$this->make(\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables::class)->bootstrap($this)
```

The `bootstrap` function of this class is where the environment variables get read. As @Devon has stated, if it's cached it won't read, if it's not, it will read from here.

So I suppose to answer your question, yes. You can run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And it won't be read on every single request. However, I think there's a disconnect between what a `session` and what an `env` is.

The answer is **there is no direct correlation**. An `.env` file is simply a list of variables that the application can re-use -- or -- are used to configure aspects of your application. The overhead of this processing is very minuscule (tested at ~1ms with a ~500 line env). You shouldn't be concerned with this level of micro-optimization.